# How use a few foreignkey in view.py django and make some logic?

Tags: python, django

I have some models

```
class Apartment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    floor = models.IntegerField()
    square = models.FloatField()
    conditioner = models.BooleanField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    status_of_apartment = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Payment_status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Rent(models.Model):
    id_client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    id_outlet = models.ForeignKey(Apartment)
    start_time = models.DateField()
    finish_time = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Payment(models.Model):
    id_rent = models.ForeignKey(Rent)
    id_payment_status = models.ForeignKey(Payment_status)
    method_of_payment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_payment = models.DateField(True)
    summ_of_payment = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

And In view I want to write status payment for the rent.

I have payment 1.12.2015 250$

Apartment cost 125$ it's 2 month.

15.12.2015 - status active
25.06.2015 - status not active.

pseudo code:

```
rent = Rent.get(pk=1)
costApartment = rent.id_outlet.cost
active_payment = payment.count([payment.id_payment_status.name = "paid", id_rent = rent.id, data_of_payment.addMonth(summ_of_payment / costApartment) > now()]) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `objects` after the `Rent`, but I did it for you here and gave you some examples:

```
rent = Rent.objects.get(id=1)
apartment_cost = rent.id_outlet.cost
payment = Payment.objects.get(id_rent=rent)
date_of_payment = payment.date_of_payment
....
```

So the first one is to create a variable called rent and assign it to `Rent` with and `id=1`. With that I could easily get the cost of the Apartment since you have a ForeignKey in your `Rent` model to the `Apartment` model. So we went from Rent to the id_outlet which links us to the Apartment model, and from their we accessed the price. Easy right? ForeignKeys make them easier for you, you can jump from one place to another easily just by connecting them well, which I say you did pretty well! Hope that answered your question.

Try not to call your FK fields like client_id or rent_id as you did in your question, because you are referring the whole model `Client` and not just the client's id, so it's better to you `client` as the field. Same goes for the `rent_id.

Comment: How I make date condition: data_of_payment.addMonth(summ_of_payment / costApartment) > now()]) > 0 ?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to get from that condition? I can't understand the code.

Comment: I have rent and some payment for rent. I want to get payment_status for rent. it is not payment status for payment. if we have active payment (made last month, eg) - we have status - "active". if payment was in last year - it's "not active".